# Should I send username and password in each request after authentication along with token?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am using default guard `api` in Laravel and for front end i am using angularjs.

**Angular Js code to fetch data from server**

```
$http({
    header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    url: apiUrl + "apiViewProfile?api_token=" + $cookies.get("Token"),
    method: 'POST'
});
```

after fetching the result in front end, I changed username and password in database manually. but I am still able to fetch results because of token.

Should I send Username and password also in each request along with token?

Answer (score 0):

No. What you can do is invalidate the token once user changes his username/password.

If you are just saying that you logged in to a different user - in this case you must clear the cookie.

Comment: I am on localhost and after authenticated i am in profile page. Then i manually changed username and password and kept the token intact. Now http request is being validated with no issues because in request i am sending only token

Comment: Works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You need to just pass the token only. not need username and password

### Info

> You just store your token on your backend and set some time for clear the token. So once you reach the time, the token will be clear and religion the screen.

Comment: What if i am using two devices. Android and Desktop to access the webpage. After authentication...i am saving the token in cookies. Then let's say i changed the user name and password in one device and in other device my token is still saved. How will i get to know that the credentials are modified?

Comment: But your backend token session time is same. So it will be timeout and all session will be clear

Comment: I am not using Session Guard. I am using Token Guard.